# Pushing to a bare Git repo fails while it is performing checkout to a worktree

Tags: git

I have a bare repository that has a linked worktree. From my tests I see that pushes into the repo fail when it's checking out into the worktree at that exact moment, i.e. it cannot checkout existing commit simultaneously with receiving pushes. Why does it happen? Is that related to some locking inside Git?

Comment: A bare repository *doesn't* have a working tree, which is what makes it suitable as a target for `git push`. Do you mean you used `git worktree add` to add a working tree to an otherwise bare repository? This is ... not a good idea, as you're discovering.

Comment: Yes, I use the latter.

Comment: Well, you can't do that. Why git allows it I don't know, but it doesn't work. Make a clone from your bare repository to where you need to keep your working directory.